LTspice ac simulation error
I am trying to simulate my circuit given below, but I don't understand what  the issue is.  I also shared the error log below.
The issue is especially related to V, but what should I do to solve it?
Another issue is d. I will not connect it to anywhere, but just use it in the equation.





Above image from answer to "Control to output transfer function" by Verbal Kint, edited by Mhan and posted on Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange is licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0.

Mhan - Thanks for adding a link to the source of the copied material. But... When material from Stack Exchange (SE) is copied/adapted (even when used elsewhere on SE) the CC BY-SA 4.0 license applies (same as Wikipedia) and that adds extra obligations on people who copy/adapt it. Adding just a link to the source is not enough to comply with that license (e.g. missing attribution for the author, missing name & link to license). Please see here for detailed guidance. Please edit the question to comply with that CC BY-SA 4.0 license.

Hello sir, I am sorry for the source, I didn't know that. I tried to update it , is it okay now ? @SamGibson♦

Mhan - Thanks for improving the reference to try to comply with the CC BY-SA license. Just to let you know, I added links to the usernames & corrected the site name (we are Electrical Engineering, not Software Engineering - that's just an example on the page I linked). Also, the original answer was recent and is licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0 not 3.0 (again, the mention of 3.0 is just an example in the linked guidance). So I fixed that & linked to the license. || That's all OK now. Let me know if you have questions.

Mhan - One question: Is that last image the only part in the question which was copied from the answer by Verbal Kint? (Notice how I added blockquotes to show that was copied material. If there is any more copied material, it should also be clearly marked as being copied, by adding blockquotes.) || One suggestion: If you want to refer to specific images (e.g. the "3rd photo" you've mentioned) it's good to label them in the question e.g. "Figure 1", "Figure 2" etc.) and refer to "Figure 1" etc. in comments.

Start by having a static definition for v(d) <-- that will be the unevaluated parameter referred to in the 3rd line. In other words, you can't use a voltage source with an output called "d" and expect it to be resolved inside a .param expression because v(d) is a time-changing variable.

How does it works then in the 3'rd photo which I add it now, same circuit, same d  @Andy aka

@Mhan you should not extend questions once an answer is provided. There's good reasons for answerer's and good reasons for you. Starting a new post is the way to get the most out of this site and it means questions (as originally asked) don't suffer from goal-post changes or mission drift. And, asking a new question means you open that post to the whole floor. I would highly recommend that you remove the addition you have just made to this question.

But, if you want a short answer; it works because you can modulate a source with another source because they are both time dependent circuit elements whereas .param is static and defined once (at the start)

Parameters are evaluated at the beginning of the simulation, they can't be time-varying.
Try using a behavioral voltage source bv for V3.

I will try your suggetion sir but How does it works then in the 3'rd photo which I add it now, same circuit, same d  @Spehro 'speff' Pefhany
